# Centralized multi-account logging for AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, amazon-cloudfront

Let me preface this by saying that I have discussed this problem in detail with advanced AWS support engineers and they have no reasonable solution, so this may be an impossible problem. However, I thought I'd give it a shot here and see if someone has a creative solution.

**The problem:**

- We have an AWS organization with multiple accounts, and multiple different accounts use CloudFront distributions.
- In accordance with AWS recommendations / best practices, we have a centralized logs archive account that collects all of our logs from all organization accounts.
- We need to collect CloudFront logs from each CloudFront distribution in each organization account, and store them in our logs archive bucket in the centralized logging account.
- CloudFront supports two logging options: (a) logging directly to S3, and (b) "Real-Time Logging" to a Kinesis data stream.
- Option (a) would be ideal, but CloudFront uses the archaic S3 ACL system and requires the "Full Control" ACL on the bucket being logged to. In order to configure this, the user/role that is configuring CloudFront must have either the "Full Control" ACL as well or the "s3:PutBucketAcl" IAM permission (so it can grant an ACL to CloudFront).
- If we grant "Full Control" ACL or the "s3:PutBucketAcl" permission to the org account, that account can then grant full access to any other entity they please, and there's no way to restrict who they grant permissions to (there's no IAM condition key that supports restricting who ACLs are granted to). Additionally, they could write objects to the bucket other than CloudFront logs. This is unacceptable for multiple reasons since we don't necessarily have a high level of trust for this account.
- Furthermore, we would have no way to control which path in the bucket they configure CloudFront to log to, which is unacceptable because we need CloudFront logs to go to a specific path in the bucket. We could use the bucket policy to deny "s3:PutObject" to anything other than the path we want, but then if the account specifies an incorrect path, the logs just won't get written and will be lost to the ether.
- Option (b) could work, but due to the fact that Kinesis data streams don't support resource policies and AWS doesn't support cross-account role passing, there's no way to have CloudFront send logs to a central Kinesis stream in the logging account. We would need a Kinesis data stream in *each* org account that uses CloudFront. This would become quite expensive.

So, I'm pretty much out of ideas. AWS's suggestion, after weeks of discussion and debate, was to:

1. Send CloudFront logs to an S3 bucket in the org account.
2. Use a Lambda that triggers on object puts to read the object and send the data to CloudWatch.
3. Put a CloudWatch subscription on the log group to send the logs to a Kinesis Firehose in the log archives account, which would then store them in the S3 bucket.

This is also an unacceptable solution though, because it creates a ton of extra resources/cost and has a lot of points of failure.

So, if anyone has any bright ideas or details on how they centralized CloudFront logs for their organization, please let me know!

Comment: May be this may work: Create CloudFront logs in the member account(s) and use cross-region replication to replicate those logs to a bucket in your centralized log account.

Comment: I've tried that as well. Unfortunately, since you can't specify the destination prefix in S3 replication, and you can't restrict which path the user sets for S3 logging in CloudFront, there's no way to prevent them from using a prefix of `/` and having all their files go to the root of your recieving bucket (when I need it to go to a path like `/cloudfront/account_id/*`).